# Is it possible to run a playbook from my mac When Ansible controller is on AWS VM?

Tags: ansible

I am working on mac where VS is installed. My Ansible controller is AWS VM and I have two control nodes on AWS.
I have been told VS code Ansible plugin helps but that plugin is now retired

Answer (score 1):

Yes, install Ansible on Mac and use the controller inventory with public IPs of the nodes and allow SSH access:
`ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml`